# how to add change keys of array and add the keys from another array values in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, logic

I have a array

```
 $arr=array(
        [0]=>a
        [1]=>b);
```

and i have another array

```
 $arr2=array(
            [0]=>array(
                 [0]=>3
                 [1]=>4)
             [1]=>array(
                 [0]=>5
                 [1]=>6)
               );
```

and i want the 2nd array look like this

```
 $arr3=array(
            [0]=>array(
                 [a]=>3
                 [b]=>4)
             [1]=>array(
                 [a]=>5
                 [b]=>6)
               );
```

that means i want to replace the 2nd array keys with first array values,
2nd array keys keys can be multiple

thanks in advance.

Comment: hint: `array_combine`

Comment: array combine not work because 2nd array is multiple i need do in foreach loop

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani why sir?

Comment: I don't see in your question any attempt to solve the problem you're asking others to solve. You just stated what you need. Feel free to read the link I provided and why such questions deserve a downvote. In short, you shouldn't expect people to write code for you (though at times they do). You can tell them what you have done and why it didn't work, then, they can help you better and more efficiently to solve your problem.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani i guess this is a genuine question i tried and i failed to do it so i asked this question you can not do that

Comment: @Boni , Welcome to StackOverflow, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first. Also, if you've tried, you could share the code which method did you attempt

Comment: okay @towkir i understand can i delete this question

Comment: You don't have to, but you can improve this. just follow the link I posted earlier. and also don't get hurt bcoz of other's comments, it's just the way things work here. people are more eager to help when they see you've tried something, no matter how much of a beginner you are :)

Comment: @Towkir am not beginner and this just a one part of my answer i write a algorithm for excel sheet upload and submit data in database but i could not implement the code so i asked of course i can prove it thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean _you_ are a beginner, I meant about anyone (that's just metaphorical). You don't need to prove, I meant improve. Anyway. Happy coding !!

Comment: @Towkir thanks for your suggestion and i knew that  i need lot of improvements and yes i am new in `SO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_combine](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) with simple `foreach` loop as:

```
foreach($arr2 as $e)
    $arr3[] = array_combine($arr, $e);
```

If you want the second array to change and not create third one use:

```
foreach($arr2 as &$e)
    $e = array_combine($arr, $e);
```

Comment: I found it amusing to watch the progress of the other answer... edit, edit, edit ... delete. Possibly because this is the way to do it. +1

Comment: yes i did thanks and why downvote @nick am i did some mistake asking this question?

Comment: @Boni I didn't downvote, but the person who did left a comment saying why they did. Generally there is an expectation that you will at least post an attempt at solving a problem yourself when asking a question.

Comment: @Boni the only expectation is that you post some code that you tried. Of course if you can't solve a problem you should ask.

Answer (score 0):

> **[array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) -  Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array**

```
$res = [];
array_walk($arr2, function($v, $k) use ($arr,&$res){
  $res[] = array_combine($arr, $v);
});
```